# Adobe Fireworks _s1 Appended to all Slice Names

Tags: fireworks

Since I started using Fireworks CS5.1, and it doesn't matter how I write the file name while exporting the slice, it always adds _s1 at the end, anyone knows how to turn that off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked options while exporting? You can adjust the pattern for the file name. _s1 indicates state 1 so it's there by default as there is at least one state in the file.

Comment: Sorry I was using the Motorola pad so I clicked the -1 by mistake, thank you for your reply